# uncaught syntax error while trying to send html - php website form

Tags: javascript, php, html, webforms

Looking for some advice / help on solving this error when trying to send an html form to an email that is verified using php.

The form for some reason sends on one server with 1 hosting company, but not with a different company on a different server and I get the Uncaught syntax error in google chrome.

If I leave a field blank, the error message is shown which works on both websites, but if I fill in all the fields, on my personal website, the form sends showing a confimation message, but on the other website, the form does not send and does not show the confimation message, even though it does show the error message if a field is left blank?

The javascript is...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// this is the id of the form
    $("#H_booking_form").submit(function(e) {
    var string_msg = '';
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "email_send.php",
           data: $("#H_booking_form").serializeArray(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
              **var data  = $.parseJSON(data);** //This is what google chrome is highlighting as the error

              if(data.status) {
                $("#message").removeClass("hide alert-danger").addClass("alert-success");
                $('#message').html(data.message);
               //console.log(data);
// show response from the php script.
              } else {
                console.log(data);
                $("#message").removeClass("hide alert-success").addClass("alert-danger");
                string_msg = data.message.join('<br />');
                console.log(string_msg);
                $('#message').html(string_msg);
             }
           }
         });
    e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
</script>
```

Thank you for any help or advice

Comment: Likely as not you are sending the email with an invalid FROM address on the server that does not work. Did you check that?

Comment: Emails not being sent, looks like nothing to do with the js code, as the error line is in the `success` event

Comment: _Snall suggestion_ I would run the `e.preventDefault();` as the first thing in this js code and not the last.

Comment: If you added `dataType: "json",` to the ajax parameters and made the PHP code return a json string using `json_encode()` then you could remove the `var data  = $.parseJSON(data);` line as jQuery would do it all for you by magic

Comment: Cheers RiggsFolly, your last answer was the solution, as I still had my own email address as the form recipient and I changed it to on on the new website / server and all worked good, cheers and would mark as answered, but know greyed out ick to mark as green.

Comment: Great, onwards and upwards